# recycleview takes all the space over relative layout

Tags: android

I have a layout like this

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >



    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

    </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

I want the admob view to take the space and then all the remaining view should be taken by the recycleview.
What's happening is recycleview takes all the space and admobview is not shown at all, unless I put hard coded height for recyleview,,

What's the best way to fit this relativelayout or just the admob view below the recycleview without hardcoding..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout`. Within the relative layout, align the `AdView` along the bottom of the screen, and put the `RecyclerView` on top of the `AdView`.

Comment: what should be the layout_height value of RecycleView when I put it above AdView ?

Comment: You should be able to use `match_parent`, just make sure you are also using `android:layout_above="@+id/adView"`

Comment: Yes I am and it works, thank you I wasted 2 hours struggling with it :(

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    >
```

when you put match parent it will take all the room, but specifying weight will allow it to expand. You also don't need RelativeLayout here as well.

Comment: tried this, for some reason its not working as expected, the banner shows up at the bottom but the recyclerview doesnt show up at all..

Comment: @Ahmed did you get rid of the RelativeLayout?

Comment: @Ahmed I believe the main problem is `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` on your AdView.